# Google Tag Manager - one container, two domains

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are about to deploy GTM but I am only able to supply one container, is there a way that we can ensure the container only fires the Analytics code on the live environment even if the code is deployed to staging?

Comment: Are you using one GA property per domain? Or are you tracking both the staging and prod sites into the same property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring your GA tag to fire only on "Some pages".
When selecting this options, you can create a rule that says:
Variable `Page hostname` equals `YOUR_LIVE_DOMAIN`.

This should effectivly allow only pages on your live environment, to be tracked by Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a go, I appreciate it!